# Add page break in TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I'm completely new to JasperReports and now trying to create relatively simple print form for some document. Print form should be presented in two pages. I added break to one of the bands just after some static text. In source code it looks like the following:

```
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                <font size="9" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[(position, signature, explanation)]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <break>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="146" width="554" height="1" uuid="f7a88926-19f1-4de4-bdbd-9104679c4b3d"/>
        </break>
    </band>
```

When I test my print form in preview mode in HTML format I don't see any sign of page break in HTML code. On the first page of print preview I see text that should be placed on the second page.

Adding a page break is supposed to be simple. What did I wrong?

P.S. Version of Jaspersoft Studio is 6.6.0.

Comment: As you can find by yourself exploring the source code of JR, there is no code for inserting "page-break" at html exporter (*HtmlExporter* class)

Comment: BTW, any chance for you to use another exporter (pdf, for example)?

Comment: @AlexK Thank you! This limitation is quite surprising. Yes, I can use PDF but there is a requirement to support HTML too. I assume that it is not possible to insert some html tag with style `page-break-after: always`. I've tried but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out there was a checkbox "Ignore pagination" for some reason set to true in the report properties. After I'd unchecked it the page breaks appeared in the report in both HTML and PDF formats.