# Break pages using Jaspersoft with generic element html

Tags: html, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

In this project I'm using Jaspersoft to generate a PDF with a HTML file. My data is in Oracle DB and I need to break pages when the height of my page is equal to the A4 height paper. Inside the HTML I have some tables (in HTML) that when render the content in Jaspersoft, it fills a unique page and my text become really small to fit in ONE page, but I need a page breaker to the next page and the size be normal of the text.

This is my jasper xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Generic builds html" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3b57bb02-2ef6-4e75-bbaf-d3792e9998cd">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.3310000000000004"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="htmlCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select *
  from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DUMMY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="742">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <genericElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="742" uuid="0dfdabd5-565a-4d75-a52e-c251867941fd"/>
                <genericElementType namespace="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/html" name="htmlelement"/>
                <genericElementParameter name="htmlContent">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$P{htmlCode}]]></valueExpression>
                </genericElementParameter>
                <genericElementParameter name="scaleType">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA["RetainShape"]]></valueExpression>
                </genericElementParameter>
                <genericElementParameter name="verticalAlign">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA["Top"]]></valueExpression>
                </genericElementParameter>
                <genericElementParameter name="horizontalAlign">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA["Left"]]></valueExpression>
                </genericElementParameter>
            </genericElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And this is a print of the PDF:
[image pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIrIe.png)

As inspiration, I used this as example: [Add page break in TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53839445/add-page-break-in-tibco-jaspersoft-studio)